# Error in Datatable: Cannot display correct number of rows

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatable, datatables

I am using angularjs and datatable. I can perfectly display the data but I have a problem in pagination and displaying of rows. The number of rows displayed on load of the page is 10 and the UI somewhat shows like this:

Show 10 entries

But it displays all the data and not just only 10, after I reload the page for several times, it would display the correct number of rows but sometimes it will return an error that in jquery.dataTables.min.js that mData is undefined and sometimes there is no error. How can I correct the displayed number of rows onload of the page?My code goes like this in html

```
<div style="width: 90%;">
            <table class="table" id="HistoryTB" >
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                UserName
              </th>
              <th>
                Time And Date
              </th>
              <th>
                IP Address
              </th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="item in HistoryData">
              <td>
                {{item.Username}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{item.TimeandDate}}
              </td>
              <td>
                {{item.IPaddress}}
              </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

and in my controller, I have this kind of code:

This is for the datatable:

```
$(function () {
        $('#HistoryTB').DataTable({
           'paging'      : true,
          'lengthChange': true,
          'searching'   : true,
          'ordering'    : true,
          'info'        : false,
          'autoWidth'   : false
        })
  })
```

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer now. As a general rule of thumb you should never do some DOM manipulations in your controller as it's causing all sort of synchronization problem between the document and your model.
To solve your problem you could either write your own directive to wrap the Datatable plugin or use one of the existing directive. Search for AngularJS DataTables and you'll find plenty of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call the .dataTable() function only after the entire data is loaded. I think your problem is that the ng-repeat renders the table after the function is called. You should use the 'data' property of datatable to generate the table instead of using ng-repeat.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

```
$(function () {
    // code to fetch HistoryData
    $('#HistoryTB').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': true,
      'searching'   : true,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : false,
      'autoWidth'   : false,
      'data'        : $scope.HistoryData
    })
})
```

Or you should wait sometime for the ng-repeat directive to finish before calling the .dataTable() function.

```
//code to fetch HistoryDate
$timeout(function() {
    $('#HistoryTB').DataTable({
      'paging'      : true,
      'lengthChange': true,
      'searching'   : true,
      'ordering'    : true,
      'info'        : false,
      'autoWidth'   : false
    })
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thanks! yeah I think that s the problem